# Where to find this FlowPanel?

Tags: .net, wpf, flowlayoutpanel, flowpanel

I have found many sources referencing a WPF class called `FlowPanel`. There is even a MSDN entry about `FlowLayoutPanel`. But my Intelisense can't find it when I type in my XAML:

```
<Flow
```

I can't find it in the toolbar neither. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure? I can only find the reference for such a control from Windows Forms...

Comment: @H.B. you are right. But I first found this name when reading a WPF book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlowLayoutPanel is a WindowsForms control, so you will not find in in WPF. You can try the [VirtualizingTilePanel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VirtualTilePanelFillMod.aspx), I think it has the functionality which you are looking for.

Edit: Also, I forgot about the [Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot). There is a neat class called AnimatingTilePanel.

Answer (score 4):

[FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx) is a WinForms control. You want the WPF equivalent, which is called [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx).